# A specific need in MS Excel of dependent drop down values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have one column where i have values called domain and another column which has  values called role.

there can be multiple roles for a domain e.g.

```
Domain Role
A       XYZ
A       ABC
B       DEF
C       DHG
A       LKJ
B       OIO
C       CND
```

etc.

I have in same sheet or a different sheet a column containing unique values in column Domain and in the next column i have to display a dropdown based on selection in the Domain column.
example if someone selected B in the domain dropdown in one row, then the role column of the same row should display in the drop down only values which are specific to B values in the roles shown above i.e. DEF & OIO

Comment: Take a look at Debra Dagleish's Contextures website [Dependent Dropdowns from Sorted Lists](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal13.html).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it is acceptable to have the master table sorted and both tables in the same worksheet, the simplest solution entails just a relatively short data validation formula.

I have set up my example worksheet as follows:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Enter this formula as the source of the In-cell dropdown List data validation of `E2`:

```dart
=INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(D2,$A:$A,0)):INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(D2,$A:$A,0)+COUNTIF($A:$A,D2)-1)
```

The beauty of this formula is that it adapts to changes in the master table, including inserting a new row at the top and appending a row after the last one.

The disadvantages are:

- The master table must be in the same worksheet
- The master table must be sorted
- Other tables on the sheet cannot safely intersect the Domain column unless they are guaranteed not to contain values matching the master table's Domain values

More complex solutions exist to overcome all these limitations.

---

Okay. Just to keep Rajesh S [happy](//chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78718), (and prove him wrong ;-) um, no, you *don't* need an array formula to either generate a unique list, *or* generate a dependent/filtered list, **if the source list is sorted**), here is the worksheet updated to include the creation of the unique domains list and the dropdown validation formula in column `D` that uses it:

[image: Updated Worksheet Screenshot]

The **normal, non array-entered** formula entered into `C2` and then filled down is:

```dart
=T(INDEX($A:$A,IFERROR(MATCH(C1,$A:$A,0),ROW())+COUNTIF($A:$A,C1)))
```

The data validation formula for `D2` is:

```dart
=INDEX($C:$C,MATCH("Unique",$C:$C,0)+1):INDEX($C:$C,MATCH("Unique",$C:$C,0)+ROWS(C:C)-COUNTIF(C:C,"")-1)
```

Comment: Friend **#robinCTC**, how excel will move automatically to D3 to filter Domain B's  Role values in E2 (for Drop Down). Don't you think that one more Drop Down is required in D2 to rotate A,B & C, are in fact the criteria to pull the related Role into the Drop Down you have created in E2.

Comment: **Continue,,,,,** and the formula will not filter the list  since formula needs to be CSE.

Comment: @RajeshS The OP stated *"I have in same sheet or a different sheet a column containing unique values in column Domain"*. That clearly means they have already worked out how to get the unique Domain values. Whether they are using a dropdown list or have a fixed set of values (like I've shown) is up to them. I've only supplied the requested solution *"in the next column i have to display a dropdown based on selection in the Domain column"*. Nowhere in the question did they ask how to construct a dropdown of unique Domain values. If they need that and request it, I will supply it.

Comment: Btw, I noticed you seem to be using **#** as in **#robinCTC** a lot. You need to use an `@` as in @RajeshS to notify a user (ping them), that you posted a message, not #. The owner of the post always gets notified. You explicitly need to ping other users. See the details of how it works in this meta post [How do comment @replies work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/).

Comment: **#robin** ,, check this one in the formula MATCH(D2,$A:$A,0), currently D2 has A so that it's filtered related roles but, unless it  will not B in D2 how could Excel match it with it's Role to filter. And how the Formula Pull B in D2 automatically even if it's unique list of Domain.

Comment: that I know ROBIN, presently @ to pull user name is not working  so that I've used different one :-)

Comment: Whether `@` auto-displays a list of users or not is irrelevant. You can just manual type the first three characters of a user's name **and it will still work**. Just like this - @raj. Typing `**#robin**` or `__#robin__` **does absolutely nothing**. As for your comments about my answer, I'm sorry, but I really don't understand what you are talking about. I suggest you follow all the steps to re-create my answer, test it, and see how it works. Then if you still have questions, feel free to ask. You can just type a `B` in `D2` and you will see that the dropdown in `E2` will change to `DEF`,`OIO`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78718/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-robincts).

Answer (score 0):

*You need to create Dependent Dropdowns.*

[image]

**Follow these steps:**

- In B304 write haeder, LISTA and put values in rows below as shown in
  screen shot.
- Select B305:B307 and Sort the range in Ascending order. Then name
  this range, "ListA".

**N.B.** *Follow above written steps for ListB & ListC also.*

- Select B304:D304 and name this range, ROLE.
- Select E304 then go to DATA Tab then click Data Validation.
- Under Setting Tab for Allow pick LIST and for Source write `=Role`.
- Place cell pointer in cell G304 and reach again to Data validation.
- Write `=INDIRECT($E$304`) in Source textbox.

**Note,** *then after as soon you select Domain name from first Drop Down Excel will filter related roles in the adjacent Drop down, as you can see in the Screen Shot.*

**N.B.**

- Adjust the cell address according to your need.
- If you feel you cab replace LISTA, LISTB & LISTC with A, B & C.